# How do I program bigram as a table in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, markov-chains

I'm doing this homework, and I am stuck at this point.
I can't program [Bigram frequency in the English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram#Bigram_frequency_in_the_English_language), 'conditional probability' in python?

> [image]
>
> That is, the probability [image: P()]  of a token [image: W_n] given the preceding token [image: W_{n-1}] is equal to the probability of their bigram, or the co-occurrence of the two tokens [image: P(W_{n-1},W_n)], divided by the probability of the preceding token.

I have a text with many letters, then I have calculated the probability for the letters in this text, so the letter 'a' appears `0.015%` compared to the letters in the text.

The letters are from `^a-zA-Z`, and what I want is:
How can I make a table with the lengths of the alphabet ((alphabet)x(alphabet)), and how do I calculate the conditional probability for every single situation?

It's like:

```
[[(a|a),(b|a),(c|a),...,(z|a),...(Z|a)]
 [(a|b),(b|b),(c|b),...,(z|b),...(Z|b)]
                    ...       ...
 [(a|Z),(b|Z),(c|Z),...,(z|Z),...(Z|Z)]]
```

and for this I should calculate the probability, like: What's the chances that you get the letter 'a' if you at this point have an letter 'a', and so on.

I can't get started, hope you  can kickstart me, and hope that it's clear what I need to solve.

Comment: Why did you massacre your own post?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Is this *suicide* or *murder*? I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file has no other punctuation (easy enough to strip out):

```
import itertools

def pairwise(s):
    a,b = itertools.tee(s)
    next(b)
    return zip(a,b)

counts = [[0 for _ in range(52)] for _ in range(52)]  # nothing has occurred yet
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for a,b in pairwise(char for line in infile for word in line.split() for char in word):  # get pairwise characters from the text
        given = ord(a) - ord('a')  # index (in `counts`) of the "given" character
        char = ord(b) - ord('a')   # index of the character that follows the "given" character
        counts[given][char] += 1

# now that we have the number of occurrences, let's divide by the totals to get conditional probabilities

totals = [sum(count[i] for i in range(52)) for count in counts]
for given in range(52):
    if not totals[given]:
        continue
    for i in range(len(counts[given])):
        counts[given][i] /= totals[given]
```

I haven't tested this, but it should be a good start

Here's a dictionary version, which should be easier to read and debug:

```
counts = {}
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for a,b in pairwise(char for line in infile for word in line.split() for char in word):
        given = ord(a) - ord('a')
        char = ord(b) - ord('a')
        if given not in counts:
            counts[given] = {}
        if char not in counts[given]:
            counts[given][char] = 0
        counts[given][char] += 1

answer = {}
for given, chardict in answer.items():
    total = sum(chardict.values())
    for char, count in chardict.items():
        answer[given][char] = count/total
```

Now, `answer` contains the probabilities you are after. If you want the probability of 'a', given 'b', look at `answer['b']['a']`

Comment: I didn't know what was easier, but im gonna try this, and see what I get.

Comment: should I change 'path/to/input' unto my file name? or there where I have the frequences of the letters from the text?

Comment: Yes, change `path/to/input` to your filename

Comment: @py.codan: what's wrong? I'm adding the dictionary solution, which is much more readable

Comment: `print total`  gives me this error:
`NameError: name 'total' is not defined `

Comment: @py.codan: You might need to update your post with exactly what code you're trying, and a full traceback

Comment: I forgot to type : 
`expect:  
   pass`

Comment: but I got a `counts[given][i] /= totals[given]
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` at the first post u gave.

Comment: @py.codan: I highly recommend you go with option (2). It's far more readable

Comment: It doesn't work either, I want it to be like a big table, but when I say `print total` at the option (2), it's says that 'total' is not defined.

Comment: @py.codan: I need to see your code, exactly. Edit your post with your current code, and I'll try to debug

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, can I get your email?

Comment: @py.codan: I'm not going to do your homework for you. You've already asked another question about this same problem. Therefore, I strongly encourage you to try it yourself. If you really, _really_ want my email, it's *really* not that hard to find

Comment: I didn't ask for your mail to do my homework, please don't understand it like that.
It was meant so I could send you my current code, as you asked for.
Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You could just as easily add your current code to your question - you clearly know how to edit your own post. That way, you're likely to get help faster rom the rest of the community as well

Comment: ?
What does the this "answer" refer to?
 Because it's assigned to an empty dictionary?

Comment: @py.codan: I've explained what `answer` does in my post. It starts off as an empty dictionary, which then gets populated with stuff

Comment: Is the idea that there must be a collected dictionary with all the letters and probabilities?

Comment: @py.codan: I'm not sure what that means. `answer` contains all the conditional probabilities of the the characters in the input file. These probabilities can be accessed as shown in my answer