# How should I handle this IndexError

Tags: python, list, error-handling, character, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to code this [Bigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram#Bigram_frequency_in_the_English_language), I've this code but it keeps given me:

```
counts[given][char] += 1 
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know how to handle it. Can anyone help me?

```
def pairwise(s):
    a,b = itertools.tee(s)
    next(b)
    return zip(a,b)
    counts = [[0 for _ in range(52)] for _ in range(52)]

with open('path/to/open') as file:
    for a,b in pairwise(char for line in file for word in line.split() for char in word):  
        given = ord(a) - ord('a')                                                            
        char = ord(b) - ord('a')                                                             

        counts[given][char] += 1
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback: counts[given][char] += 1 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why not remove the `try` and see what exception is raised then?

Comment: Look at the indent of `counts`

Comment: I get this Traceback:
`counts[given][char] += 1
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That last line in your pairwise will never be executed. If you're going to copy [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27951905/198633), do it right. `counts` needs to be in the same scope as `with(open)...`

Answer (score 1):

Your `counts` variable is a *local in the `pairwise()` function*.

As such, trying to access `counts` *as a global* in the `for` loop will raise a `NameError`. But you instead silenced that exception with a blanket `except`. Don't do that. See [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice) for example. If you wanted to ignore *index errors*, then catch *just* that exception, explicitly:

```
except IndexError:
    print 'failed'
```

and let other exceptions reach you so you can correct errors.

Unindent the `counts` line, it is not meant to be part of the `pairwise()` function:

```
def pairwise(s):
    a,b = itertools.tee(s)
    next(b)
    return zip(a,b)

counts = [[0 for _ in range(52)] for _ in range(52)]

with open('path/to/open') as file:
    for a,b in pairwise(char for line in file for word in line.split() for char in word):  
        given = ord(a) - ord('a')                                                            
        char = ord(b) - ord('a')                                                             
        try:
            counts[given][char] += 1
        except IndexError:
            # unknown character, ignore this one
```

Note that for anything outside lowercase ASCII letters (a-z) you'll produce indices that are either too large or negative. `ord('a')` is 97, but *uppercase* letters range from 65 through to 90. This'll mean you end up with integers ranging from -32 through to -5. That may not be what you wanted.

Comment: I get this Traceback:
`counts[given][char] += 1
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What should I do? Im completly blank.

Comment: Do about what? The exception? Did you read all of my answer? The code sample I give includes a `except IndexError` handler.

Comment: @py.codan: the exception you show me is caught by that exception handler. If it isn't you are not using the same code.

Comment: If u go up and see the question again, I've edited it a bit, so the `except` isn't there, and I get as you said `IndexError`.

Comment: @py.codan: and if you read my full answer carefully, you'll see that I tell you that if you need to catch specific exceptions, then you need to do so. I warn against a **blanket** exception handler, not against specific exceptions. My answer then goes on to show you code that uses an explicit exception handler for `IndexError`.

Comment: I'm simply lost in your answer. I'm thinking that I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: The last codeblock is a full replacement for what you posted. Can you see what differences there are between the two?

Comment: That I posted let the idle give us the IndexError, while at the last codeblock we are excepting this happen.